# Implementation of Room queries in Android Room

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

As the documentation regarding these topics seems to be limited (and I was searching a lot - either wrong or the documentation is really limited), I would like to place the question here.

So far I could only find documentation that shows how to implement the basic CRUD operations (insert, delete, update, deleteAll, getAll) in the Android Architecture Components, but never queries which only return a single item. In general, the question is: Is the idea to hold all information in the repository by holding LiveData of all table contents and returning single objects from the repository?

### Let me precise the question in two cases:

> 1. One table / entity
> 2. Two tables / entities with a 1:many relationship

**One table**
I fully get the concept of using LiveData for a single table, which I can use in a recycler view to list all table rows. But in many cases, I only need one row/object to work with. For example when editing one item.

**Question 1:** Is it common to implement a method on the repository to get the needed item out of the LiveData<List> allObjects like below? Of course, I could also pass all information from the last activity to my editActivity through my intent, but I find it easier to implement if I just pass the ID of an object and load it in my editActivity.

```
private LiveData<List<object>> allObjects; 

public void getObjectById(int id){
    for (Object o : allObjects) {
        if(o.getid() == id){
            return o;
        }
    }
```

**Two tables**
I also get the idea of having two entities and defining their relation in a separate class. Let's use a common example from the documentation: school with students (1:m).

**Question 2:** Is it common to hold LiveData<List> in my repository?
In my recycler view, I could use this list to display (for example) all schools with their number of students. Therefore I might not need the LiveData allSchools anymore.

**Question 3:** What is the best way to implement a query which returns me a student and the school he is visiting? I could implement a (relationship) class StudentWithSchool and keep LiveData of it in my repository.

```
private LiveData<List<StudentWithSchool>> allStudentsWithSchool;

public void getStudentWithSchoolByStudentId(int id){
    for (StudentWithSchool s : allStudentsWithSchool) {
        if(s.getid() == id){
            return s;
        }
    }
```

It would be really helpful if somebody can explain to me how to implement the above examples correctly. Thank you, guys!

Comment: If id in your example is unique you can just query using that and return 1 object. no need to fetch all then loop and return the one matching id.

    @Query("SELECT * FROM 'yourtable' WHERE id = :id")
    YourObject getObjectById(int id);

Comment: @Per.J yes, the id's in my examples are meant to be unique. 

From what I have learned, is that JetPack is not offering a one shot read (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries). I need to use LiveData for that. But that frequently leeds to null exceptions in my code... Can you advise me how to implement this on the repository and the ViewModel properly?

Comment: My dao query example is showing a read that returns 1 row if it exist not a list.

If you are not running the query in a background thread you can wrap the answer in a LiveData<YourObejct> like so, still don't need to be a list with all rows

Comment: @Per.J I tried that and it works for the first case, where I have only one table. But for the second case - with a 1:m relation where I want to get "a student with its school", the repository returns null. May I ask you to put the required code in the relationship class, the dao, the repository and the ViewModel into the answer? That most likely would resolve my issues - as it sounds like I am just implementing it wrong...